# QueryDSL JPA syntax error with contains on Set?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, querydsl

I have a JPA entity bean similar to the following:

```
@Entity
class License {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "LicenseTags")
    Set<Tag> tags;

    // Skipped remaining members
}
```

`Tag` itself is also an `Entity` with an id and a name. Now I want to query for licenses that have certain tags attached to them.  When I try the following query

```
Set<Tag> tags = ...;
final QLicense license = QLicense.license;
JPAQuery q = new JPAQuery(entityManager).from(license);

for (Tag tag : tags) {
    q.where(license.tags.contains(tag));
}

Collection<License> result = q.listDistinct(license);
```

I get the following Exception on the line with `listDistinct`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [select distinct license
from License license
where ?1 in elements(license.tags)]: unexpected token [in].
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(35!=[685:1: inExpression[boolean not, Object left] returns [Object node] : (t= IN n= inputParameter | t= IN LEFT_ROUND_BRACKET (itemNode= inItem ( COMMA itemNode= inItem )* | subqueryNode= subquery ) RIGHT_ROUND_BRACKET );])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1328)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:425)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.DefaultSessionHolder.createQuery(DefaultSessionHolder.java:35)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.createQuery(AbstractJPAQuery.java:139)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.createQuery(AbstractJPAQuery.java:108)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.list(AbstractJPAQuery.java:276)
    at com.mysema.query.support.ProjectableQuery.listDistinct(ProjectableQuery.java:104)
```

From the parser exception output I can only guess that maybe there are parenthesis missing.

Am I doing something wrong to query for values contained in the set?

I am using GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.0.1 (build 22) which in turn uses EclipseLink Bundle-Version: 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600

Regards, Tilmann

Comment: Try using JPA solution maybe? `CriteriaBuilder.in()`.

Comment: Actually the above is only an excerpt and there are a lot of other search criteria executed in the same query. We just migrated that away from CriteriaBuilder to QueryDSL because the CB syntax version of the query had grown really obscure. ;)

Comment: I agree with you, nice choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are using the Hibernate templates in your JPA query. Try this instead

```
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery (entityManager, EclipseLinkTemplates.DEFAULT);
```

From the next release on there will be an autodetection of the JPA provider and proper templates for JPQL usage will be chosen based on that.

The current logic is described though in the reference manual http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.6.0/reference/html/ch02.html#d0e185

Also you might try to express your query like this

```
List<License> result = query.from(license)
    .where(license.tags.any().in(tags))
    .listDistinct(license);
```

Comment: Thank you Timo very much for this insightful reply. I was not aware that dialect templates have to be selected :) This fixed the syntax problem I had :) But: The abbreviation query presented by you does not work as expected. I documented this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088064/querydsl-duplicate-identification-variable-equality-syntax-error-with-any-on-set

Comment: Ok, I will look into that issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

Could be the lack of brackets, or could be 'elements', I'm not sure it is part of JPQL.

Try executing the JPQL directly to determine what is wrong.

You query also seems very inefficient, you should just use a join from license to tags instead.

Comment: Yes for the check mentioned I could use a join :) But then I'd get into trouble for the next step to implement: List only licenses that do _not_ have any of the given tags. Performance is not an issue in our use of the query.